# Error when trying to connect to LDAP with TLS 'LDAP Result Code 201 "ErrorNetwork": Invalid packet format'

Tags: ssl, go, ldap

I'm trying make an authentication service with LDAP and TLS using http://www.github.com/mavricknz/ldap
When I use only basic authentication using the following code, everything works just fine.

```
conn := ldap.NewLDAPConnection(ldapHost, ldapPort)

conn.NetworkConnectTimeout = time.Duration(ldapConnTimeout) * time.Millisecond
conn.ReadTimeout = time.Duration(ldapReadTimeout) * time.Millisecond

if err := conn.Connect(); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    resp.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}

defer conn.Close()

// bind to ldap
if err := conn.Bind(username, password); err != nil {
    ldaperr := err.(*ldap.LDAPError)
    if ldaperr.ResultCode == ldap.LDAPResultInvalidCredentials {
        resp.Header().Set("WWW-Authenticate", `Basic realm="Item Codes Database"`)
        resp.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
    } else {
        log.Println(err)
        resp.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
    return
}
```

but when I try to applying TLS to my code by changing

```
conn := ldap.NewLDAPConnection(ldapHost, ldapPort)
```

to

```
ldap.NewLDAPTLSConnection(ldapHost, ldapPort, &tls.Config{})
```

It gives me an error `LDAP Result Code 201 "ErrorNetwork": Invalid packet format`. That error comes from method `conn.Connect()` which when I dig into it, it didn't even reach the point where the TLS config or TLS flag has been used.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Next week I will try using the [go-ldap](https://github.com/go-ldap/ldap) library, which is a more updated fork of mavericknz's, and has a fairly recent [Fix StartTLS patch](https://github.com/go-ldap/ldap/pull/5) which I'm hopeful will help. I'll be sure to submit an answer if this, or something else, proves fruitful. I hope you'll answer your own question, too, if you find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found my solution. I need to change the port from ldap's 389 to ldaps' 636 because we use TLS protocol. And I also has to use method `NewLDAPSSLConnection` instead to establish an implicit TLS connection.

I'm not sure why `NewLDAPTSLConnection` does not work. It use explicit TLS which require us to establish a normal connection first (which use port 389) and then attempt to start TLS over that connection.

Comment: Does your LDAP server support STARTTLS on port 389? Evidently not.

Comment: This is a work-around, not a proper solution. It seems there is a bug in `NewLDAPTLSConnection()`.

Comment: @EJP: I don't know about the OP's LDAP server, but I've had the same problem on a large number of LDAP servers which do support TLS, and work when making a connection from Perl, but not with the Go library. I think it's a bug in the Go lib.